I am writing thesis report in twosided format in overleaf I want the certificates, declarations, etc to be specifically in single sided any idea HOW?
How to convert specific pages to onesided in twosided environment.
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


You mean that there is content with length of more than one page that must be included as if it were onesided? In your (twosided) pdf this would lead to blank pages.
Please be more specific about what you are asking for.

You hav not provided any usable example (none of the packages you show are relevant, and you show no actual document text to test) but the usal mechanism before frontmatter that must appear on the right hand page with nothing on the opposite side is to use \cleardoublepage before each section such as title, acnowledgements, etc

For entire pages, \newgeometry and \restoregeometry (geometry package) are ideal.

@codeR The duplicate question is about onecolumn/twocolumn. But IMHO the question is about oneside/twoside or something like this (maybe about openright/openany, IMHO this is currently unclear).
